# Accessing Socket.io variable in different files (Express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying to make a basic chat application using express.js and socket.io. I have two cofiguration files which are `bin/www` and `app.js.` My app starts from `bin/www`. That is where I create my http server.

`bin/www`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
require('babel-register');

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('jukebox-messaging-api:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}

module.exports = {
    io: io
};
```

I define my io object in this file and I export it.

When I try to access the io object, for example in my `index_controller.js`

`routes/index_controller`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Server = require('../bin/www');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Jukebox Messaging API'});
});

router.get('/ping', function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).json("We are alive!");
});

router.get('/chats', function (req,res,next) {
   res.render('chat');
});

Server.io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("socket connected");
});

module.exports = router;
```

In here I try to require the www file and access the io object. But I get this error:

```
Server.io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index_controller.js:18:1)
```

PS: If you need to see any additional files pls comment, I will happily add them here. Thanks!

Comment: `Server.io.on('connection', function (socket) { ...` ?

Comment: Nope, the error is happening because I can not pass the object properly

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.io = io;
    next();
});
```

and then in your routes, you can use req.io.sockets.emit